# how to refresh another form when a child form is closed in c# windows application?

Tags: c#, .net

I am new in c#.
I have a `viewpatients` form where I display patient list in `gridview`. I have a edit button in that `gridview` which opens another form named `editpatient` via `showDialog()` where I can edit patients record and save. after click on save button in `editpatient` form, I want to refresh the `viewpatient` form. how this can be achieved?

viewpatient code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex==7)
    {
        DB con = new DB();
        con.constr.Open();
        string id = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value);
        MessageBox.Show("clicked" + (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString()+" and row_id="+id);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete from tbl_patients where id = '" + id + "'", con.constr);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.constr.Close();
        load_data();     
    }

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 8)
    {
        string id = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value);
        EditPatient editp = new EditPatient();
        editp.patient_id = id;
        editp.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

editpatient code:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DB db_con = new DB();
        db_con.constr.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update tbl_patients set name='" + txtName.Text+"', age='"+txtAge.Text+"', address='"+txtAddress.Text+"',phone='"+txtPhone.Text+"',doctor='"+cmbDoctor.Text+"',category='"+cmbCategory.Text+"' where id="+patient_id, db_con.constr);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        db_con.constr.Close();  
        this.Close(); 


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can `this.Invalidate();` or `this.Refresh();` to refresh the form

Comment: you need to invoke the methods above on `viewpatients` form

Comment: I tried this but not working.                                                                               private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
              //.........            
                db_con.constr.Close();                
                ViewPatients vp = new ViewPatients();
                vp.Invalidate();
                vp.Refresh();
                this.Close();   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

Comment: other thing you can try his `this.Update();` which will force a refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use DialogResult property to close edit dialog.

edit form:

```
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    try
    {
        DB db_con = new DB();
        db_con.constr.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update tbl_patients set name='" + txtName.Text+"', age='"+txtAge.Text+"', address='"+txtAddress.Text+"',phone='"+txtPhone.Text+"',doctor='"+cmbDoctor.Text+"',category='"+cmbCategory.Text+"' where id="+patient_id, db_con.constr);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        db_con.constr.Close();

        // Close edit dialog
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

view form:

using (EditPatient editp = new EditPatient())
{
     editp.patient_id = id;

     if (editp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         // refresh view dataset
         // this.refreshDataset();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Well worked this way.  Thanks a lot.                                                                                                 if (e.ColumnIndex == 8)
            {
                string id = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value);
                EditPatient editp = new EditPatient();
                editp.patient_id = id;
                if (editp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    load_data();
                }            
            }

Comment: You are always welcome. I am glad to help you, and hope you can improve many more.